# PHP variable not showing 0 after multiplying

Tags: php

Im stuck at this part of my code. So I am trying to get the 30% of a specific value but I am not getting the right output. please see value below.

```
foreach($salary->getValues() as $key => $value) {
    echo 'salary:       '.$value['salary'];
    echo 'gross salary: '.$value['salary'] * .30;
}
```

lets assume that the salary array that we are getting is 40,000 (I am already getting this in my code) now multiply it .30 the answer must be 12,000. Therefore

Expected Output:

```
salary: 40,000 gross salary: 12,000
```

What is happening

```
salary: 40,000 gross salary: 12
```

Help please

Comment: "40,000" is not a number. It's a string. PHP is trying to treat it as an integer but encounters the `,` and gives this error `<b>Notice</b>:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in <b>[...][...]</b> on line `

Comment: try my answer, subukan mo sagot ko :D, with demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"40,000" is a string. When trying to multiply, PHP tries to convert it to an integer, encounters the comma (`,`) and returns an error (but, oddly, then seems to continue the process using the int it got to before the comma)

One way would be to remove the comma before multiplying, then return it to `number format` after the multiplication.

```
$newSalary = number_format(str_replace("," , "", $value['salary']) * .30);
```

Answer (score 2):

use str_replace

```
foreach ($salary->getValues() as $key => $value) {
                    echo 'salary:       ' . $value['salary']; 
                    echo 'gross salary: ' . str_replace(',', '', $value['salary'] ) * .30 ;
                }
            }
```

Output : `1200`

DEMO : https://3v4l.org/ZdQGZ

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the result of multiplication with `money_format()` method.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

Try something like `money_format('%.3n', $value['salary'] * .30);`

Answer (score 0):

Do not use this kind of "default formatting", but format any printed value yourself...

Try something like this:

```
foreach ($salary->getValues() as $key => $value) {
   printf( "salary: %.3f gross salary: %.3f\n", $value['salary'], $value['salary'] * .3 );
}
```